# Email body Selection.Moveright run-time error '-2147221164 Class not registered

Tags: vba, outlook

I am trying to run a macro with `selection.moveright` in `vba` Outlook but I have the message `Run-time error '-2147221164 (class not registered)`.

Do you have any idea what is the kind of problem? Which reference should I install?

I already have installed Microsoft Word 16.0 and Microsoft Outlook 16.0 libraries (I have ms office 2016)

Here is the macro:

```
Function test()
    Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=5, Extend:=wdMove
End Function
```

Comment: `Selection.MoveRight` is the Word Object Model.

Comment: @BigBen I have already checked the microsoft word 16.0 object library

Comment: [Edit]ing your question with more of your code would be helpful then.

Comment: @BigBen I edited, thanks

Comment: What is `Selection` supposed to represent? The selection in the body of a draft email? You need more code than just that.

Comment: @Selection is supposed to represent selection in the body of an email

Comment: In reality I need a code to place a cursor after a specific word in email body , do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*If you are running the code from Outlook then you will need to reference Word object in your code*

*Example*

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub Example()
    Dim Inspector As Outlook.Inspector
    Dim wdDoc As Word.Document
    Dim Selection As Word.Selection


    Set Inspector = Application.ActiveInspector()
    Set wdDoc = Inspector.WordEditor
    Set Selection = wdDoc.Application.Selection
        Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=5, Extend:=wdMove


    Set Inspector = Nothing
    Set wdDoc = Nothing
    Set Selection = Nothing
End Sub
```

*Remember in this example we are working with [Application.ActiveInspector()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.application.activeinspector)*

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help... do you know a way to move cursor after a specific word in body?